# Getting error while adding CKEditor in GWT UiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, ckeditor, uibinder

I am trying to add CKEditor in my UiBinder based GWT app.
But getting following  exception:

> Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:87)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:340)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:340)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:340)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:103)
>       at com.lokur.uilibrary.widgets.disclosure.client.tabbed.TabPanelMarkup.onAttach(TabPanelMarkup.java:114)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:340)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.setParent(Widget.java:470)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.adopt(Panel.java:127)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel.add(ComplexPanel.java:97)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel.add(AbsolutePanel.java:97)
>       at com.lokur.admin.usp.motd.client.MessageOfTheDay.onModuleLoad(MessageOfTheDay.java:24)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:193)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
>   Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): $wnd.CKEDITOR is undefined
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
>       at com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.client.CKEditor.replaceTextArea(CKEditor.java)
>       at com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.client.CKEditor.initInstance(CKEditor.java:173)
>       at com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.client.CKEditor.onLoad(CKEditor.java:164)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:112)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:340)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:340)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:340)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:103)
>       at com.lokur.uilibrary.widgets.disclosure.client.tabbed.TabPanelMarkup.onAttach(TabPanelMarkup.java:114)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException$1.execute(AttachDetachException.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException.tryCommand(AttachDetachException.java:74)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.doAttachChildren(Panel.java:170)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onAttach(Widget.java:340)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.onAttach(Composite.java:103)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.setParent(Widget.java:470)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel.adopt(Panel.java:127)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel.add(ComplexPanel.java:97)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel.add(AbsolutePanel.java:97)
>       at com.lokur.admin.usp.motd.client.MessageOfTheDay.onModuleLoad(MessageOfTheDay.java:24)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:193)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

I have configured everything I know of like:

1. Added maven dependency in pom.xml:

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.axeiya.gwt</groupId>
           <artifactId>gwt-ckeditor</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. Added xmlns entry in myModule.ui.xml file:

   `xmlns:ck="urn:import:com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.client"`
3. Added widget in myModule.ui.xml file:

   `<ck:CKEditor ui:field="ckEditor" />`
4. Added corresponding ui field in MyModuleWidgets.java file:

[image]

5) Also added sources to `myModule.gwt.xml` file:

```
`<inherits name="com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.Gwtckeditor"/>`
```

6) Here is UIBinder file:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">

<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:ck="urn:import:com.axeiya.gwtckeditor.client"
             ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
             ui:generateKeys='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator'
             ui:generateLocales="default">

    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <ck:CKEditor ui:field="ckEditor2" />
    </g:HTMLPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

What might be missing?

Comment: Can you share your UiBinder file too?

Comment: @Simon-Pierre: Added UiBinder file snippet above. Thanks.